# Implementation of a specific binarySearch

Tags: java

Does anyone know where I can find the actual implementation of binarySearch in java.util.Collections? Specifically the following:

```
binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, T object, Comparator<? super T> comparator)
```

Comment: You can usually search for the file source on grepcode.com

Comment: If you use eclipse, just put the cursor at a call to the method, and press F3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each JDK installation comes with a `src.zip` file containing the public source code. The `.java` file for `java.util.Collections` is part of that.

Alternatively, you can see source at [grepcode.com by doing a simple search for `java`](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=java).